# Start ipython qtconsole as interactive interpreter after script execution

Tags: python, ipython, qtconsole

I have `ipython` with `qtconsole` installed and can start it via `ipython qtconsole`. I can also run a script via `ipython -i my_script.py` to stay in the interactive interpreter after the script finishes or if an exception is thrown. But I could not figure out how to combine them: I would like to do `ipython -i qtconsole my_script.py` but whatever I try, it complains about invalid flags. Any hint how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting, it seems that either this option was forgotten or not wanted in the qtconsole. A way around this (or perhaps an intended way?) is to use the `-m` flag. This runs a module as a script so you if you called:

```
ipython qtconsole -m my_script
```

it will run the code in `my_script`, for me this works. Notice it needs to be `my_script` not `my_script.py` otherwise it will throw an error since it's looking for the module not the file. Hope that helps.

Comment: Works for me with and without ending, but gives a unknown failure at the end in case of using the ending

Comment: This is because the `-m` flag is looking for a module. So it looks in the current directory for a file named `my_scipy.py`, if you call it with `-m my_script.py` then it will look for `my_script.py.py`. More information on import modules and writing your own can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: How to run qtconsole from source code? In other words: what is source code of `%qtconsole` magic?