# Run python script in IPython with inline / embedded plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, inline, ipython

I'd like to have a batch file in one folder with a `python` script. The batch file should call the script in `IPython` and plot the figures inline / embedded. Though there is lots of info on this around, I failed getting this to work.

- **How to run a `python` script with `IPython`, showing plots embedded?**
- Do I need to use `pylab` or can I just import `matplotlib.pyplot` in the script?
- Do I have to adapt anything else in the script?
- Is `%pylab inline` / `%matplotlib inline` to be used or not?

The latter commands give

```
In [1]: %pylab inline
UsageError: Invalid GUI request u'inline', valid ones are:[None, 'osx', 'qt4', 
'glut',   'gtk3', 'pyglet', 'wx', 'none', 'qt', 'gtk', 'tk']
In [2]: %matplotlib inline 
UsageError: Invalid GUI request u'inline', valid ones are:  [None, 'osx', 'qt4',
'glut', 'gtk3', 'pyglet', 'wx', 'none', 'qt', 'gtk', 'tk']`
```

Up to now I tried the following (luckless)

```
ipython --pylab=inline example_plots.py
```

Gives me the following and quits

```
E:\CD\package\bin>ipython --pylab=inline example_plots.py
WARNING: 'inline' not available as pylab backend, using 'auto' instead.
WARNING: 'inline' not available as pylab backend, using 'auto' instead.
```

or from console it runs but as usual with figures popping up (and closing right away):

```
E:\CD\package\bin>ipython --pylab=inline example_plots.py
WARNING: 'inline' not available as pylab backend, using 'auto' instead.
WARNING: 'inline' not available as pylab backend, using 'auto' instead.
Using matplotlib backend: Qt4Agg
# runs python script as usual (not inline)
```

Following [How to make IPython notebook matplotlib plot inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410042/how-to-make-ipython-notebook-inline-matplotlib-graphics)
With the batch file (and the same with the console):

```
ipython notebook --pylab inline example_plots.py
2014-01-26 17:52:10.101 [NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: u'C:\\Users\\Robert\\.ipython\\profile_default'
2014-01-26 17:52:10.111 [NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
2014-01-26 17:52:10.127 [NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: E:\CD\package\bin
2014-01-26 17:52:10.128 [NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://127.0.0.1:8888/
2014-01-26 17:52:10.128 [NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

Opens an empty notebook and thats it.

What else should I try?

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
IPython 1.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

Comment: I think you're trying to use the `inline` option in the terminal - that won't work, because the terminal isn't capable of displaying graphics. `inline` requires the Qt console or the Notebook. But I'm not sure what you're trying to embed the figures in?

Comment: @ThomasK How to distinguish terminal and console?

Comment: What do you mean? IPython has the Qt console (`ipython qtconsole`), which is capable of displaying graphics.

Comment: @thomask so only qtconsole can do that. I thought a can run a script which has some plots in it with ipython so that the **plots will not pop up in separate windows but are shown within the console instead**. Is that possible?. I tried `ipython qtconsole --pylab inline example_plots.py` which launches the console, but thats it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start ipython qtconsole als interactive interpreter after script execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295132/start-ipython-qtconsole-als-interactive-interpreter-after-script-execution)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Greg answered it here: 
[Start ipython qtconsole as interactive interpreter after script execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295132/start-ipython-qtconsole-als-interactive-interpreter-aft)

It works using the `-m` flag

```
ipython qtconsole --matplotlib inline -m example_plots
```

or

```
ipython qtconsole --pylab inline -m example_plots
```

But I do not know, what makes the difference between those two options `pylab inline` and `matplotlib inline`. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528503/1797098) I figure, that I'd rather use `--matplotlib inline`

Even adding the file ending it does what I want to, but it complains about `unknown failure` after execution.

`pyplot.show(block=True)` will give and `unknown failure`, too

Comment: `pylab` imports a whole bunch of stuff, but it's discouraged now because that makes it hard to see where things are coming from. `matplotlib` sets up the mpl backend, but doesn't import things into the user namespace.

Answer (score 2):

How to run a python script with IPython, showing plots embedded?

- You need to use the qt console.
- Run `ipython qtconsole <yourscript.py>`.
- If you have jupyter installed, the better.
- Run `jupyter qtconsole <yourscript.py>`

Do I need to use pylab or can I just import matplotlib.pyplot in the script?

- Run `%matplotlib inline` prior to importing matplotlib.pyplot.

Is %pylab inline / %matplotlib inline to be used or not?

- Yes. But pylab has been depreciated. Use `%matplotlib inline`.