# %matplotlib linline produces error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code which is regular for anyone who would like to make a plot with pandas in IPython.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [4]: %matplotlib inline
```

Here it pops up an error:

```
UsageError: Invalid GUI request u'inline', valid ones are: pyglet, osx, qt5, qt, glut, gtk, gtk3, tk, wx
```

I read this post [Run python script in IPython with inline / embedded plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366672/run-python-script-in-ipython-with-inline-embedded-plots)

and found the two methods to get around:

```
ipython qtconsole --matplotlib inline -m example_plots
```

or

```
ipython qtconsole --pylab inline -m example_plots
```

But none of them works in my situation (I actually got stuck in iPython without making a plot, needless to say a plot embedded within a script.)

I am not sure where went wrong as `%matplotlib inline` used to work. I am using python 2.7.11 and IPython 4.2.0 if this information helps.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Try `%matplotlib inline` before importing `pyplot`.

Comment: perhaps you might want to run the code in a notebook? Or is that not an option?

Comment: M.T.'s suggestion works. IPython Notebook does the work.  Thank you both!